# Why setting `\XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping = 2` causes problem to two `\fontspec` in sequence?

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I encountered one strange problem with `\fontspec` and `\XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping = 2` setting. If I use more than one `\fontspec` in sequence in a line, I got an error. All those commented line with `% problem` (above or on the right of the line) caused error. Please notice the small differences regarding spaces at the end of the first `\fontspec` and before the beginning of the second. To my surprise, the last two lines work again there even though they are exactly the same as line 32 and 35. I suppose line no 38 must have suppressed the error somehow.

If I remove `\XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping = 2`, they all work fine. But I need it so that my Burmese text is justified properly.

Although I can use those lines which are okay as workarounds for my need, I am curious why this problem happens.

```
\documentclass[twoside, openright]{book}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "my_MM"  %Myanmar line and character breaks
\XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping = 2

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand{\class}{\myCodePar{class}}
\newcommand{\turnLeft}{\myCodePar{turnLeft}}

\newcommand{\myCodePar}[1]{{\fontspec[Scale=1, Script=Latin]{Ubuntu Mono} #1}}

\definecolor{myParColor}{HTML}{4E4D4D}
\definecolor{myParColor1}{HTML}{4E4D4E}


\begin{document}

%\noindent\myCodePar{MeetKarel}\class\ \turnLeft  % problem

%\noindent\myCodePar{MeetKarel} \class\ \turnLeft % problem

%\noindent\myCodePar{MeetKarel}~\class\ \turnLeft % problem

\noindent\myCodePar{MeetKarel }\class\ \turnLeft  % okay




% problem (note: if i set different color to these two fontspec, it works)
%\noindent {\fontspec[Color=myParColor]{Ubuntu Mono} MeetKarel} {\fontspec[Color=myParColor]{Ubuntu Mono} class}

% problem (note: if i set different color to these two fontspec, it works)
%\noindent {\fontspec[Color=myParColor]{Ubuntu Mono} MeetKarel}~{\fontspec[Color=myParColor]{Ubuntu Mono} class}

% okay
\noindent {\fontspec[Color=myParColor]{Ubuntu Mono} MeetKarel}{\fontspec[Color=myParColor]{Ubuntu Mono} class}

% okay
\noindent {\fontspec[Color=myParColor]{Ubuntu Mono} MeetKarel }{\fontspec[Color=myParColor]{Ubuntu Mono} class}

% okay !Same as line 35, but it works here, not there
\noindent {\fontspec[Color=myParColor]{Ubuntu Mono} MeetKarel}~{\fontspec[Color=myParColor]{Ubuntu Mono} class}

% okay !Same as line 32, but it works here, not there
\noindent {\fontspec[Color=myParColor]{Ubuntu Mono} MeetKarel} {\fontspec[Color=myParColor]{Ubuntu Mono} class}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Never use `\fontspec` in the document. It’s better to define the needed fonts in the preamble or to use `\addfontfeatures`.

Comment: Hi @egreg, does that advice also apply to macro? I am writing a technical book in Burmese. Many a times I need to sandwich english words in between, for various reasons. What is the best way to approach this need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\fontspec` is definitely not recommended: you're always recomputing the same settings all the times.

Define a font command, instead.

```
\documentclass[twoside, openright]{book}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "my_MM"  %Myanmar line and character breaks
\XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping = 2

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\newfontfamily{\ubuntumono}{Fira Mono}[Script=Latin]% replace Fira with Ubuntu
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textubuntumono}{\ubuntumono}

\newcommand{\class}{\myCodePar{class}}
\newcommand{\turnLeft}{\myCodePar{turnLeft}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myCodePar}{om}{%
  % #1 = optional color, #2 = text
  \textubuntumono{\IfValueT{#1}{\addfontfeatures{Color=#1}}#2}%
}

\definecolor{myParColor}{HTML}{4E4D4D}
\definecolor{myParColor1}{rgb}{1,0,0}


\begin{document}

\noindent\myCodePar{MeetKarel}\class\ \turnLeft  % problem

\noindent\myCodePar{MeetKarel} \class\ \turnLeft % problem

\noindent\myCodePar{MeetKarel}~\class\ \turnLeft % problem

\noindent\myCodePar{MeetKarel }\class\ \turnLeft  % okay

\noindent \myCodePar[myParColor]{MeetKarel} \myCodePar[myParColor]{class}

\noindent \myCodePar[myParColor1]{MeetKarel} \myCodePar[myParColor]{class}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't have Ubuntu Mono on my system, so I replaced it with Fira Mono, but it's mostly irrelevant.

Anyway, the fact that your code gives a segmentation fault should probably be investigated upon.

Comment: imho the main point is that one should use a textcommand as that inserts the italic correction code. For me `{\ttfamily abc} {\ttfamily abc} {\ttfamily abc}` crashes (even without fontspec), while `{\ttfamily abc\/}  {\ttfamily abc\/} {\ttfamily abc\/}` works. That looks like an engine bug.

Comment: @egreg, thanks! As suggested, I will define and use font commands I need accordingly.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, that should be fixed. Anyway, the workaround even provides cleaner code…